# Can a region of the $xy$ plane be infinite in area and topologically closed?

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

Is it possible to create a region in the $xy$ plane that has infinite area but contains all of its boundary points?  In other words, if I am introducing a theorem that begins: "Let R be a closed region in the $xy$ plane", do I need to also specify that R is finite?

Comment: _Closed_ can mean multiple things, including: topologically closed (contains all its boundary points), or enclosed by one or more loops (a Jordan region), or (in the theory of surfaces) compact and boundaryless. If one convention isn't clear from context, your readers will thank you for being explicit.

Comment: Thanks.  I've edited the question to hopefully clarify

Comment: Trivially yes, $\mathbb R^2$ as it is open and closed. But maybe you are thinking in a proper subset.

Comment: I believe so.  I think I meant that it is strictly closed, not clopen.  Does that change things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your concern in the comments, it's [a theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Connected_iff_no_Proper_Clopen_Sets) that a topological space contains nontrivial clopen sets (sets other than $\emptyset$ and the space itself) $\iff$ the space is disconnected.  Because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, any nonempty, proper, closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not also open.

Since closed sets are defined to be the complements of open sets, your question will have an affirmative answer if we can establish the existence of open sets of finite area.  Such open sets exist; in particular, the [metric topology](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MetricTopology.html) has a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) consisting of the collection of open balls of finite radius.

Comment: Is it totally equivalent?  The complement of an closed set with infinite area is an open set, but not necessarily with finite area.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at.  Fixed.

Comment: Do I need to specify that my region is simply connected in order for the answer to be affirmative?

Comment: Though path-connected, the complement of any open ball won't be simply connected, and yet it is a closed set with infinite area.

Answer (score 2):

What about the region
$$
    D = \left\{(x,y)\mid x \geq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1/x\right\}
$$
A few more examples came to mind, but then I wasn't sure on the definition of region.

Comment: I believe I meant "simply connected domain".  intuitively, in the finite case, a "region" in my definition is a "shape" that can be drawn in the plane that does not contain any pinch points...forgive my lack of rigour :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a proper subset:  $\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq x \}$